# the registrar cannot marshal the parameter type 'system.action' in xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hello everyone I am working on the project related to the WebView and everything is fine so far. When I use WKNavigationDelegate and build with simulator it is working but when I try to build with the real device it gives me an error and I cannot publish my app.
Any help would be appreciate thank you.

1. Error MT4136: The registrar cannot marshal the parameter type 'System.Action`2<WebKit.WKNavigationActionPolicy,WebKit.WKWebpagePreferences>' of the parameter '?' in the method 'WebKit.IWKNavigationDelegate.' (MT4136) (midssamIOSXamarin)
2. Error MT4136: The registrar cannot marshal the parameter type 'System.Action`2<Foundation.NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition,Foundation.NSUrlCredential>' of the parameter '?' in the method 'WebKit.IWKNavigationDelegate.' (MT4136) (midssamIOSXamarin)
   [image]

```
namespace midssamIOSXamarin
{
   public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
   {
     public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
     {
     }

     public override void ViewDidLoad ()
     {
         base.ViewDidLoad ();

         var configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
         var controller = new WKUserContentController();
         configuration.UserContentController = controller;

         var webView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, configuration);
         webView.UIDelegate = new JavascriptUIDelegate();
         webView.NavigationDelegate = new JavascriptNavigationDelegate();
         this.View.AddSubview(webView);
         
          webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest("test url"));      
      }
   }

   public class JavascriptUIDelegate : WKUIDelegate
   { 
    public JavascriptUIDelegate()
    {
         
    }

    public override void RunJavaScriptAlertPanel(WKWebView webView, string message, WKFrameInfo frame, Action completionHandler)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create("", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("확인", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

        var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
        rootVC.PresentViewController(alert, true, completionHandler);
    }

    public override void RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel(WKWebView webView, string message, WKFrameInfo frame, Action<bool> completionHandler)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create("", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("확인", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => completionHandler(true)));
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("취소", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, action => completionHandler(false)));

        var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
        rootVC.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }
  }

  public class JavascriptNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
  { 
    public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
    {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
    }
    public override void DidFailNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
    { 
    }
    public override void DidFailProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
    { 
    }
    public override void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {  
    }
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    { 
    }

    public override void DidCommitNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {  
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Please post code and error as text

Comment: Could you check please I have just edit my question thank you.

Comment: @AkmalBukhariev Hi, do you use `https` of the website and other Certificate authentications?

Answer (score 1):

I am also a developer using xamarin.
I had the same error when I tried to implement the sample WebView app.
The most effective way to deal with it was to enable the Mono interpreter.

1. Click on the project name in the solution explorer to open the
   project options
2. Open the "iOS build" tab
3. Check "Enable Mono interpreter"

In my case, the above method solved the problem.